# Prevent multiple instances of a winform app

Tags: c#, winforms

All, I am trying to prevent multiple instances of an app, What I want to do is closing the last process, and running a new process for the app. Currently I knew I can stop running multiple instances for a winform application like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93989/prevent-multiple-instances-of-a-given-app-in-net). But I want to know how to close the last one safely. I don't want to use the `Process.kill` method to terminate the app. I want to close it safely. So far I think the code should look like below .  please help to review it .thanks.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
   using(Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\" + appGuid))
   {
      if(!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Instance already running");
         //close the last one. 
         //......I don't know how to make it.  
      }

      Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
}

private static string appGuid = "c0a76b5a-12ab-45c5-b9d9-d693faa6e7b9";
```

Comment: Why are you closing last one? Simply don't start new one

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Because the app have some start up parameters , maybe they are different every times when the app starts up. so , What I want to do is running the app with the new parameters , If don't start new one, you know , the parameter for the app is old. not the ones I want to use. thanks.

Comment: You can pass parameters to already running instance

Comment: Could you please tell me how to pass the new parameters to already running instance? thanks.

Comment: I think you need some kind of IPC (Inter-Process Communication). I usually use WCF which is quite easy for such a goal.

Comment: It is a built-in .NET feature, use the WindowsFormsApplicationBase class.  Set its IsSingleInstance property to true, use the StartupNextInstance event to know what arguments were used for the 2nd instance.  Sample code [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923785/run-one-instance-of-program/11923963#11923963)

Comment: @HansPassant, years ago I wrote my own code to do this leveraging the Windows API to check the title of the window (man how I've grown); but I still didn't know about this. Thanks a lot friend, that will save me later in life I'm sure!